# Why does RAID configuration on AWS EBS provide extra safety?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I do not understand why AWS still encourages RAID configuration on EBS. I thought the volumes are replicated mutliple times within a single AZ. Optionally they can also be replicated to another AZ.

On GCP you don't need to do this RAID configuration. The documentation explicitly discourages this.

Quote: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/raid-config.html

> Creating a RAID 0 array allows you to achieve a higher level of performance for a file system than you can provision on a single Amazon EBS volume. **A RAID 1 array offers a "mirror" of your data for extra redundancy.** Before you perform this procedure, you need to decide how large your RAID array should be and how many IOPS you want to provision.

Note, I am talking about **safety** / **fault-tolerance** in this question. I am not talking about performance, but at least from the GCP documentation they discourage striping disks together even for performance reasons:

Quote: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks

> Compute Engine optimizes performance and scaling on persistent disks automatically. **You don't need to stripe multiple disks together or pre-warm disks to get the best performance.** When you need more disk space or better performance, resize your disks and possibly add more vCPUs to add more storage space, throughput, and IOPS

Comment: It's right there on that page: "For greater I/O performance than you can achieve with a single volume..."

Comment: In the title I explicitly stated for **safety**

Comment: @ceejayoz Maybe I understood the documentation wrong and indeed they mean redundancy in terms of performance. But when somebody mentions redundancy I think of safety of the data. The claim is generally true for RAID 1, but has little value in my opinion in the context of EBS.

Answer (score 3):

Just because the data is replicated multiple times within AZ, it doesn't mean the durability is 100%.

If you consider `gp2` volume type, its durability is [99.8% - 99.9%](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/features/#Amazon_EBS_Availability_and_Durability) which might not be the worst but compared to S3 that has 99.999999999% durability, it is lacking a bit.

RAID 1 is indeed safer from the perspective of data durability. AWS is not telling you that this is **the** correct option, instead, it is one of the options if you need any. You can as well create EBS snapshots and/or use another data replication strategy (or you might be OK with the above-mentioned numbers in which case you don't need to do anything else beyond provisioning EBS volume in this regard).

Comment: It is true that the durability is not 100%, but even with two EBS volumes it is not guaranteed that these are probabilistically decoupled. Means: you cannot control whether the two EBS volumes are on the same storage cluster or not. So in my opinion it doesnt make sense to use RAID on EBS for fault-tolerance.

Comment: I also think it's not worth the effort to set it up even though it gives slightly higher safety. Creating the snapshots and replicating across regions should give us enough safeguard already.